# How private is the nature of German funerals? How welcomed are uninvited people?

Tags: germany, culture

Where I come from if you attend an uninvited planned funeral of a friend, family, acquaintance, it's much appreciated and is taken as a sign of respect for the deceased and their family.

I heard that father of a close person I know was deceased. I was told by my friend that it is planned for that specific date. Being raised in my culture I instantly thought I should attend, but then came the question.

Answer (score 2):

It’s ok to attend with a good reason, for example for the father of a close friend. Especially if the close friend is there.

I’d expect that family and friends of the father would be invited, but others would be welcome.

Comment: Appreciate your input. Should it be first arranged? Or do people just show up?

Comment: Personally, I would give the close friend a call and turn up unless they Nothing would be specifically arranged.